# How to make HTML5 speech recognition not ask permission every time

Tags: html, google-chrome, permissions, microphone

I have created a script that requires my microphone. It uses the HTML5 speech recognition API. Chrome asks permission every time I want to perform a speech recognition test.

Javascript (partial) code that I am using:

```
         var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
            recognition.continuous = true;
            recognition.interimResults = true;
            recognition.onresult = function(event) {
                console.log(event.results[0][0].transcript);
                if(event.results[0][0].transcript === 'print')
                {
                    console.log('');
                }
            };

            recognition.start();
```

I have tried to add it into the list of exceptions in either Chrome and Flash player, but it still asks for permission.

Printscreen:

[image: Print screen example]

That message pops up everytime I click the button.
Is there any way to disable Chrome for asking permission?

Comment: Does this happen when it's accessed via SSL?

Comment: I think not, but I have no legit ssl certificates available to do that. Is there no other way?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to bypass that (yet).  See http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API - bolded text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As jschorr mentioned in the comments above, only using HTTPS will prevent the browser from asking for permissions every time recognition  is started

As clearly stated [here](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API)